# VBA Insert row instead of copy

Tags: excel, vba, insert, range

I'm trying to run before I can crawl.  I have pieced together this code, but I need it to Insert at row 24, not copy.

```
Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh4 = Sheets("est")
Set sh5 = Sheets("gaf letter")
lr = sh4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh4.Range("a1:a" & lr)
rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Rows("24:24")
```

I've attempted using .Insert, but it comes up with Method Insert of object Range Failed. The code works fine if I wanted to just copy, but I need it to insert and shift the remaining rows below it, down.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit ' declare all variables

Sub InsertRows()

    Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, rng As Range
    Set sh4 = Sheets("est")
    Set sh5 = Sheets("gaf letter")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With sh4
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Rows("1:" & lr)
        rng.Copy
        sh5.Rows(24).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just go

```
With Sheets("est")
    .Range("A1", .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("gaf letter").rows(24).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```